# "Missing credentials" with PassportJS when I put enctype="multipart/form-data" and an input[type="file"]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

## THE PROBLEM

I've got a problem, when I use enctype="multipart/form-data" to my form (with an upload (.jpg/.png, etc.)) and I sumbit it, my flash displays "Missing credentials", without precisions. So how do I fix this ?

## What I've tried

I searched solutions, but no one answered my problem. So I tried to resolve this, during 1-2 hours. I've found nothing. I asked too in another forum (alsacreations.com, if you know)

What I know, it is NOT a problem with my config/passport.js because otherwise, in my console, I would have logs.

## Some code

```
[2] GET /api/auth/user 304 0.621 ms - -
[2] GET /api/auth/user 304 0.816 ms - -
[2] GET /favicon.ico 200 0.072 ms - 2780
[2] GET /assets/dist/app.js 304 1.433 ms - -
[2] GET /signup 304 2.842 ms - -
[2] POST /api/auth/user 200 5.250 ms - 2
[2] POST /signup 302 0.951 ms - 58
[2] GET /signup 200 3.036 ms - 3596
[2] GET /assets/styles/main-css.css 304 0.919 ms - -
[2] GET /assets/dist/main-js.js 304 2.542 ms - -
[2] GET /assets/dist/app.js 304 1.797 ms - -
[2] GET /assets/config/config-en.json 304 0.720 ms - -
[2] GET /assets/dist/manifest.json 304 0.584 ms - -
[2] GET /api/auth/user 200 0.529 ms - 5
[2] GET /api/auth/user 304 1.049 ms - -
[2] GET /assets/dist/app.js 304 0.994 ms - -
[2] GET /signup 200 4.576 ms - 3376
```

As you see it there's no log...

## Let's the demo!

https://forum.alsacreations.com/upload/1559134328-67719-alsa.png

- I've a form (with enctype="multipart/form-data", etc.)

https://forum.alsacreations.com/upload/1559134431-67719-alsa.png

- I upload my picture (as it happens an avatar)

https://forum.alsacreations.com/upload/1559134534-67719-alsa.png

- BUT (else it'll be too easy...)
  When I upload it, I've got this message ("Missing credentials"), is there any callback that I've not caught? (I wanna have more informations)

Thanks for your help.

(Sorry I can't place images, I'm under the 10 points of reputations, lol)

Answer (score 0):

Before you handle logic of upload image, have you checked user is logged in or not? By req.isAuthenticated() like this:

```
app.get('/some_path', checkAuthentication, function(req,res) {
    // your logic upload files
});

function checkAuthentication(req,res,next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
        //req.isAuthenticated() will return true if user is logged in
        next();
    } else{
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I did!

You can see too in my github: https://github.com/Soldat8889/psearch/tree/develop in app folder, routes and signupRouter.js

```
module.exports = {
    get: (req, res, _Template) => {
        fs.readFile(`public/config/config-${req.cookies.lang}.json`, 'utf-8', (e, data) => {
            if(e) {
                // REDIRECT
                res.redirect('/lang-select');
                return;
            }

            if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
                // REDIRECT
                res.redirect('/dashboard');
                return;
            }

            res.render('main', {
                title: JSON.parse(data)['title']['signup'],
                description: JSON.parse(data)['description']['signup'],
                lang: req.cookies.lang,
                url: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}${req.originalUrl}`,
                env: nodeEnv,
                mainCSS: _Template.mainCSS,
                mainJS: _Template.mainJS,
                appJS: _Template.appJS,
                params: {
                    email: req.session.email,
                    username: req.session.username,
                    errorTarget: req.session.errorTarget
                }
            });
        });
    },
    authenticate: passport.authenticate('local-signup', { successRedirect: '/dashboard', failureRedirect: '/signup', failureFlash: true })
}
```